# Select a bunch of data given a list of key

Tags: sql, select, subquery, inner-join, where-clause

I have just started learning SQL and I have encountered a problem. I am completely new to SQL, and I do not even know which keywords to google to tackle this problem.

I have two table:

1. tablea

```
id | name
01 | abc
02 | ahb
03 | aen
04 | aev
05 | aca
06 | aee
07 | abc
08 | ahr
```

and a second one:

2. tableb

```
group | name_id
A     |    01
A     |    02
A     |    03
A     |    04
A     |    05
A     |    06
B     |    07
B     |    08
```

Let's say I want to SELECT all the names belong to group A.

I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT name FROM tablea WHERE id = (SELECT name_id from tableb WHERE group = "A");
```

However, the result only give me a single line.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT name FROM tablea WHERE id IN (SELECT name_id from tableb WHERE group = "A");
```

Answer (score 2):

For your sample data, the query should error - because the subquery returns more than one row, which is is not expected here since you are using  `=` .

If `name_id` is a unique column in `tableb`, then a `join` is appropriate:

```
select a.name
from tablea a
inner join tableb b on b.name_id = a.id
where b.group = 'A'
```

Otherwise, I would recommend `exists`:

```
select a.name 
from tablea a
where exists (select 1 from tableb b where b.name_id = a.id and b.group = 'A')
```